# Prolog - generate fibonacci series

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

I want to write predicate that generates the Fibonacci series for given N.

```
fibon(6, X) -> X = [0,1,1,2,3,5].
```

I have a predicate to generate the N-th element of the Fibonacci series:

```
fib(0, 0).
fib(1, 1).
fib(N, F) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    N2 is N - 2,
    fib(N1, F1),
    fib(N2, F2),
    F is F1 + F2.
```

And I try to write fibon/2, but it doesn't work:

```
fibon(N, [H|T]) :-
    fib(N, H),
    N1 is N - 1,
    fibon(N1, T).
```

I solved it like the following:

```
at_the_end(X, [], [X]).
at_the_end(X, [H|T], [H|T2]) :-
    at_the_end(X, T, T2).

revert([], []).
revert([H|T], Out) :-
    revert(T, Out1),
    at_the_end(H, Out1, Out).

fib(0, 0).
fib(1, 1).
fib(N, F) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    N2 is N - 2,
    fib(N1, F1),
    fib(N2, F2),
    F is F1 + F2.

fibon(0, [0]).
fibon(N, [H|T]) :-
    fib(N, H),
    N1 is N - 1,
    fibon(N1, T).

fibonacci(In, Out) :-
    fibon(In, Out1),
    revert(Out1, Out).
```

Comment: Where's your base case for the recursion of `fibon/2`? What happens if `N = 0`? or if `N < 0`?

Comment: Factually, now it works. I will actualize this question.

Comment: You really should have an `N > 0` condition in your recursive clause to avoid non-termination issues due to `N` becoming < 0. Also, your base case probably should be `fibon(0, [])` since `0` is NOT a Fibonacci number. If you have no Fibonacci numbers (0) then you should have an empty list, yes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can squeeze out a little more speed by making the recursive predicate tail recursive:

```
fib_seq(0,[0]).                   % <- base case 1
fib_seq(1,[0,1]).                 % <- base case 2
fib_seq(N,Seq) :-
   N > 1,
   fib_seq_(N,SeqR,1,[1,0]),      % <- actual relation (all other cases)
   reverse(SeqR,Seq).             % <- reverse/2 from library(lists)

fib_seq_(N,Seq,N,Seq).
fib_seq_(N,Seq,N0,[B,A|Fs]) :-
   N > N0,
   N1 is N0+1,
   C is A+B,
   fib_seq_(N,Seq,N1,[C,B,A|Fs]). % <- tail recursion
```

First let's observe that your example query works as expected:

```
?- fib_seq(6,L).
L = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8] ;
false.
```

Note that the list doesn't have six elements, as in your example at the beginning of your post, but seven. This is because the predicate starts counting at zero  (BTW this is the same behaviour as that of the predicate `fibonacci/2` that you added to your post).

For comparison (with `fib/2` from @Enigmativity's post) reasons, let's either remove the goal `reverse/2` from `fib_seq/2` (then you'd get all solutions except N=0 and N=1 in reverse order):

```
?- time((fib(50000,L),false)).
% 150,001 inferences, 0.396 CPU in 0.396 seconds (100% CPU, 379199 Lips)
false.

?- time((fib_seq(50000,L),false)).
% 150,002 inferences, 0.078 CPU in 0.078 seconds (100% CPU, 1930675 Lips)
false.
```

Or leave `fib_seq/2` as it is and measure `fib/2` with an additional goal `reverse/2` (then `R` in the `fib/2` solution corresponds to `L` in the `fib_seq/2` solution):

```
?- time((fib(50000,L),reverse(L,R),false)).
% 200,004 inferences, 0.409 CPU in 0.409 seconds (100% CPU, 488961 Lips)
false.

?- time((fib_seq(50000,L),false)).
% 200,005 inferences, 0.088 CPU in 0.088 seconds (100% CPU, 2267872 Lips)
false.
```

On a side note, I would urge you to compare your predicate `fibonacci/2` with the posted solutions when trying to get bigger lists, say N > 30.

Comment: How does it work? Why `fib_seq_` does **not** generate multiple answers? Please, someone expand the answer.

Comment: @Nishi: The predicate `fib_seq_/4` describes a relation between a given `N > 1` (`N` has to be instantiated due to the use of `>/2` and `is/2`) and a sequence of fibonacci numbers from index `0` to `N`. The predicate is called with a starting index of `1` and a starting sequence `[1,0]`. Those auxiliary arguments are incremented and padded with fibonacci numbers respectively until the target index `N` is reached. For any fixed `N > 1` this relation has a unique sequence as a solution. Why do you expect `fib_seq_/4` to produce multiple answers?

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to reverse the order of the results for the sequence then this works:

```
fib(0, [0]).
fib(1, [1,0]).
fib(N, [R,X,Y|Zs]) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    fib(N1, [X,Y|Zs]),
    R is X + Y.
```

Then `?- fib(15,Z).` gives me `[610, 377, 233, 144, 89, 55, 34, 21, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0]`.

It would be easy to throw in a `reverse/3` predicate:

```
reverse([],Z,Z).
reverse([H|T],Z,A) :- reverse(T,Z,[H|A]).
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun using `scanl`. and some standard dcgs.

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

my_plus(X,Y,Z):-
    Z#>=0,
    Z#=<1000, % Max size optional
    Z#=X+Y.

list([])     --> [].
list([L|Ls]) --> [L], list(Ls).

concatenation([]) --> [].
concatenation([List|Lists]) -->
        list(List),
        concatenation(Lists).

fib(Len,List1):-
    X0=1,
    length(List1,Len),
    length(End,2),
    MiddleLen #= Len - 3,
    length(Middle,MiddleLen),
    phrase(concatenation([[X0],Middle,End]), List1),
    phrase(concatenation([[X0],Middle]), List2),
    phrase(concatenation([Middle,End]), List3),
    scanl(my_plus,List2,X0,List3).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect a list of the first `N` elements of the Fibonacci series you can use the rule below. Just remember to initialize the first 2 predicates.

```
fib(0, [1]).
fib(1, [1, 1]).

fib(N, L) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    N2 is N - 2,
    fib(N1, F1),
    last(F1, L1),
    fib(N2, F2),
    last(F2, L2),
    L_new is L1 + L2,
    append(F1, [L_new], L).
```